# regex - between optional quotes

Tags: regex, perl, unix, scripting, character-encoding

Example of strings to search:

```
name = 'bob'
person=mary
init= 'tim', 
first =sarah,
,name=o'donnel
surny = 'o'doherty',
extend = 'marshall , mathers (111)'
```

This regex search below is erroneous:

```
[ ]*,?[ ]*(.+)[ ]*=[ ]*'?(.*)'?[ ]*(,|;)*[ ]*
```

Regex replace with 2 groups: `\1 \2`

Desired results below:

```
name bob
person mary
init tim 
first sarah
name o'donnel
surny o'doherty
extended marshall , mathers (111)
```

Pseudocode in order is basically:

```
optional spaces,one optional comma,optional spaces,any characters (grouped),optional spaces,optional spaces,one optional single quote,any characters (grouped),one optional single quote,optional spaces,one optional comma or semicolon,optional spaces
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make it non-greedy: `(.+)` -> `(.+?)` and `(.*)` -> `(.*?)`, [demo](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2vihm).